# Change All Subscribers status to Held

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking for possibility to set subscriber status to Held. I tried importing from a file and SOAP API with SSJS but this seems not to work:

```
    var subscriber = Subscriber.Init(row.SubscriberID);
    Write(subscriber.Update({
        "Status" : "Held",
        "EmailAddress" : row.EmailAddress
    }));
```

Does anyone know if it's achievabel withoud resending the email to subscriber in question?

Comment: Dod you do this in the ENT BU? It is not possible to change All Subscribers from child BU

Comment: Yes, This is a single BU Account so I'm at the top.

Comment: Documentation only mentions options 'Unsubscribed' and 'Active' for updating subscribers, so it may be that the other values can only be set by the system.

Comment: Without having done any testing, I am leaning towards Rain's view on this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Held status is a direct consequence of a bounce event when sending to a specific subscriber. I believe you cannot set one yourself.

Answer (score 3):

'Held' status cannot be set through an import, but it can be set by SOAP API. Doing so results in the All Subscriber UI showing them as Held but with "Total Bounces: None".

Example:

```
<Body>
  <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options/>
     <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
      <SubscriberKey>12345</SubscriberKey>
      <Status>Held</Status>
     </Objects>
  </UpdateRequest>
</Body>
```

Response:

```
<Body>
    <UpdateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Results>
            <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>Updated Subscriber.</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <Object xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ID>246424929</ID>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <EmailAddress>user@example.com</EmailAddress>
                <SubscriberKey>12345</SubscriberKey>
                <Status>Held</Status>
            </Object>
        </Results>
        <RequestID>600e51b0-e40d-4818-973c-6ffde31dcba2</RequestID>
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    </UpdateResponse>
</Body>
```